# Why is a linear search through a heap data structure faster than tree traversal?

Tags: java, performance, heap, cpu-cache

In the following code, `indexOfSlow` is around 17 times slower than `indexOf` in my test cases, although the former does fewer comparison than the latter.

**Why is that?**

(My hunch is that the superior performance of `indexOf` is due to sequential array access which has e.g. caching benefits - but I'd like to know for sure)

Performance numbers from my machine:

```
| elementCount | indexOf msec | indexOfSlow msec | slow/fast |
|--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------|
|        10000 |           41 |              852 |        21 |
|        20000 |          232 |             3387 |        15 |
|        30000 |          375 |             6642 |        18 |
|        40000 |          710 |            12699 |        18 |
|        50000 |         1197 |            19182 |        16 |
|--------------+--------------+------------------+-----------|
|      average |              |                  |      17.6 |
```

N.B. Java's `PriorityQueue.indexOf()` is similar to my `indexOf`, so it does not try to walk the tree and stop early like my `indexOfSlow` does.

```java
class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int elementCount = 50_000;

        final List<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<>(elementCount);
        for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
            elements.add(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            final var heap = new Heap<Integer>();
            for (int i : elements)
                heap.add(i);
            assert heap.peek() == 0;
            final long nanoBefore = System.nanoTime();
            for (int i = elementCount; i > 0; i--)
                heap.indexOf(i - 1);
//                heap.indexOfSlow(i - 1);
            final long nanoAfter = System.nanoTime();
            if (j > 0) // discard first round as warmup
                System.out.println("Time taken: " + (nanoAfter - nanoBefore) / 1_000_000 + " msec");
        }
    }

    private final ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public T peek() {
        return list.isEmpty() ? null : list.get(0);
    }

    private void siftUp(int i, T value) {
        while (i > 0) {
            int parentI = (i - 1) / 2;
            final T parentValue = list.get(parentI);
            if (parentValue.compareTo(value) <= 0)
                return;
            list.set(parentI, value);
            list.set(i, parentValue);
            i = parentI;
        }
    }

    public void add(T value) {
        list.add(value);
        siftUp(list.size() - 1, value);
    }

    public int indexOf(T value) {
        final int size = list.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                if (value.compareTo(list.get(i)) == 0)
                    return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int indexOfSlow(T value) {
        final int size = list.size();
        if (size > 0) {
            Queue<Integer> childrenToVisit = new LinkedList<>();
            childrenToVisit.add(0);
            while (!childrenToVisit.isEmpty()) {
                int i = childrenToVisit.poll();
                final int cmp = list.get(i).compareTo(value);
                if (cmp == 0)
                    return i;
                if (cmp > 0)
                    continue;
                int rightChildIdx = (i + 1) * 2;
                int leftChildIdx = rightChildIdx - 1;
                if (leftChildIdx < size)
                    childrenToVisit.add(leftChildIdx);
                if (rightChildIdx < size)
                    childrenToVisit.add(rightChildIdx);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: So this is java? Or some other language? Please add a language tag. Also, if there's not a single obvious way in which benchmarking is done with this language/platform, please add details of how the benchmarking has been done also.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, it's Java. I added the tag. The benchmark was done running the main method which is at the top of the source code.

Comment: Your benchmark is flawed. Rewrite it using JMH https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java/4480774#4480774

Comment: You benchmark the worst case scenario for the `indexOfSlow()` method: the test data in the heap is totally ordered and therefore `indexOfSlow()` has to search through the same number of elements as `indexOf()`, but it does so in a much more complicated way. Initialize your test data with 50_000 random values.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky, max/min heap is a data structure which guarantees O(1) TC for `peek` and O(log(N)) TC for add/remove, `indexOf` method does not make any sense.

Comment: In addition to what Thomas Kläger said, read [When to use LinkedList over ArrayList in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322715/2711488). You’ve chosen the worst way to store a sequence of `int` values. An `ArrayDeque` will perform much better even though it will still have the auto-boxing overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the results obtained with

```java
final long nanoBefore = System.nanoTime();
//...
final long nanoAfter = System.nanoTime();
```

are not reliable at all. To get reliable results you need to use JMH.

Second, in `indexOfSlow()` you use `LinkedList` which is highly ineffective.

Third, in `indexOf()` you don't allocate any memory, iterating over the same list again and again. In `indexOfSlow()` you allocate a new `LinkedList` for each method invocation. This obviously costs us time and GC.

Fourth, in spite of the fact that in theory linear search has complexity O(n) in practice in your example you are searching over `ArrayList` which is array-based and extremely fast when you are accessing elements by index (even if you need to iterate over the whole list). In the `indexOfSlow()` on the contrary you rely on continuous `poll()`/`add()` operations. Imagine you are looking for `49733`, then for the `1`, `2`, `3` etc. values you execute both `poll()` and `add()`operation. As a result before returning the value you are looking for your `childrenToVisit` list is modified **99734** (!!!) times. So this algorithm is extremely ineffectively implemented and this is why you have such a dramatic difference in numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Your LinkedList argument makes a lot of sense. (In hindisght, I should have come up with the myself...) I don't quite follow your and some other commentators condemnation of all microbenchmarks that don't use JMH, even though I do like and use JMH, and for a serious test it should be used. Nevertheless, nanoTime is not not reliable per se. In fact, JMH will probably be using nanoTime under the hood.

Comment: @EvgeniyBerezovsky The problem is not about JMH using something else than `nanoTime`. JMH helps to avoid common benchmarking pitfalls, and I see at least several of them in your hand-crafted benchmark, e.g., not mitigating dead code elimination by not consuming computation results, not doing warmup properly, and measuring OSR stubs instead of the fully optimized JIT compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing ~ more than reading, moreover, you are doing that in a very inefficient manner, it is possible to get some improvements if replace `LinkedList` with `int[]`:

```java
final int size = list.size();
if (size <= 0) {
    return -1;
}

int[] queue = new int[size];
int last = 0;
for (int index = 0; index <= last; index++) {
    int cmp = list.get(queue[index]).compareTo(value);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        return index;
    }
    if (cmp > 0) {
        continue;
    }
    int right = (index + 1) * 2;
    int left = right - 1;
    if (left < size) {
        queue[++last] = left;
        if (right < size) {
            queue[++last] = right;
        }
    }
}
return -1;
```

since in the worst case `LinkedList` will contain `N/2` elements, such replacement is reasonable, however, that still performs worse than DFS approach:

```java
int indexOf(T value, int index, int size) {
    if (index >= size) {
        return -1;
    }

    int cmp = list.get(index).compareTo(value);

    if (cmp == 0) {
        return index;
    }

    int res = -1;

    if (cmp > 0) {
        return res;
    }

    int rIdx = (index + 1) * 2;
    int lIdx = rIdx - 1;

    if ((res = indexOf(value, rIdx, size)) >= 0) {
        return res;
    }

    return indexOf(value, lIdx, size);
}
```

the idea of optimizing out some paths via storing information about them somewhere is not so good for this particular case - you may store indexes in `HashMap` and achieve `O(1)` TC for search operation utilising comparable amount of memory.